# Stack Overflow Blog sidebar overflows into footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

On macOS, browsing with Safari or Firefox, when you scroll down to the bottom of the [blog homepage](https://stackoverflow.blog/), you'll notice the sidebar content is overflowing awkwardly into the footer:

[image]

System: macOS 13.4.1, Safari 16.5.2 and Firefox 116.0.3

Comment: No repro on FF 117: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glJeY.png

Comment: Could you add what device and browser you're using?

Comment: No repro in FF 116.0.3, nor in Chromium 116.0.5845.110

Comment: I can reproduce with 140% zoom though (but not an equivalent window narrowing)

Comment: I can reproduce with Safari on an iPad, no zoom.

Comment: @Fastnlight which iPad? can't repro on iPad Pro 11" 2021

Comment: @Carog it could be an Apple-specific problem, I've updated the post with my system specs.

Comment: Also wanted to note... i can't see the bottom of the left menu until i scroll to the footer. cuts off halfway through the teams ad. (18" monitor)

Comment: No repro with either of those browsers on macOS.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery there's a scroll bar on the sidebar now, which wasn't there an hour ago or so. I think the devs just fixed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed to match the behaviour here on Meta and elsewhere - a scrollbar appears if vertical height is constrained. Thank you for flagging.